# erlang 'basho/lager' log app, is it possible to custom module log level?

Tags: logging, erlang

In rabbitmq's source code, there is one file, call "rabbit_log.erl". It could customize different module's log level. The customization is implemented by application environment.

for example, in `.erlang` file:

```
application:set_env(rabbit,log_levels,
        [{default,info},{aaa_connection,error}]).
```

Only `aaa_connection` module will show 'error' level, and other module will show 'info' level module.

I want to know that is it possible to customize module's log level in `basho/lager` app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lager`'s tracing feature (https://github.com/basho/lager#tracing).

```
lager:trace_file("log/aaa_connection_error.log", [{module, aaa_connection}], error)
```